# Postgres get null if row doesn't exist in where clause

Tags: postgresql

I've a postgres table with data like

| Name | Attendance |
| --- | --- |
| Jackie | 2 |
| Jade | 5 |
| Xi | 10 |
| Chan | 15 |

In my query I want all present by name, and if name doesn't exist return "null" instead of no row for that particular name

Eg
`query where Name in ('Jackie', 'Jade', 'Cha', 'Xi')`

Should return

| Name | Attendance |
| --- | --- |
| Jackie | 2 |
| Jade | 5 |
| NULL | NULL |
| Xi | 10 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To produce the desired rows, you need to join with a table or [set of rows](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-FUNCTIONS-RETURNING-SET) which has all those names.

You can do this by inserting the names into a temp table and joining on that, but in Postgres you can turn an [array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/arrays.html) of names into a set of rows using `unnest`. Then [`left join`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) with the table to return a row for every value in the array.

```
select attendances.*
from
  unnest(ARRAY['Jackie','Jade','Cha','Xi']) as names(name)
left join attendances on names.name = attendances.name;
```

Comment: @JackieChan You're welcome. And I've just been doing SQL for quite some time. Love your movies! ;)